# Image post to Server with data json not working ios

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have tried to post image with data using the following code.Data is getting upload but image is not uploading.

```
-(void)imageUpload
{
    name=@"Har9233";
    userId=@"2969";
    cityId=@"1";
    mobile=@"9888329329";
    mobileVerify=@"no ";
    gender=@"1";

    //NSString *imageData=@"12";

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);
    NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [_params setObject:userId forKey:@"userId"];
    [_params setObject:name forKey:@"profileDisplayName"];
    [_params setObject:gender forKey:@"gender"];
    [_params setObject:cityId forKey:@"cityId"];
    [_params setObject:mobile forKey:@"mobile"];
    [_params setObject:mobileVerify forKey:@"isMobileVerified"];

    NSString *boundary = @"ghkyre–nhjfhdj-74f5f-gfg5-gggff";

    NSString* FileParamConstant =@"image";

    //
    NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // post body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // add params (all params are strings)
    for (NSString *param in _params) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

// add image data


if (imageData) 
{
        NSLog(@"2");
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"harryimg1.png\"\r\n",FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];       
}

// [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:Nil];

NSDictionary *jsonResponseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSLog(@"DATA=%@",jsonResponseData);

}
```

Comment: What code you use in the server side ? Can you post some server side code here ?

Comment: Uncommenting the line `// [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` will probably fix it. However, it appears that you are not quite certain how to setup a multipart/form-data: please read [RFC 2046 § 5.1.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.1) carefully.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problems, and have been using a code quite like yours. Try this, it works for sure, that is what I am using:

```
- (NSString *)randomStringWithLength:(int)length
    {

        NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random() % [letters length]]];
        }

        return randomString;
    }

-(BOOL)uploadImageFile:(NSString *)filename
    {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourUrl"]];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
        NSString *boundary = [self randomStringWithLength:14];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
        NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
        [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
        [request setHTTPBody:postbody];

        NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
        NSError *requestError = nil;
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

        if (((NSHTTPURLResponse *)urlResponse).statusCode != 201) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to upload file: %@, response data: %@, response code: %i, request error: %@", [filename lastPathComponent], [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)urlResponse).statusCode, requestError);
            return NO;
        }

        NSLog(@"Uploading File Successful");
        return YES;

    }
```

Comment: You did not setup the multipart/form-data message correctly (no boundaries). I doubt that this "works for sure", since your body will be interpreted as _preamble_ and thus, ignored. See [RFC 2046](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046), [Section 5.1.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.1).

Comment: Are you sure there is no boundary? And how would I succeed to use this if there isn't any?

Comment: Yes, the _post body_ (multipart/form-data body) does not contain a part which starts with the boundary-delimiter, and it does not close with a close-boundary-delimiter. Are you sure, your request succeeded? (this depends on the content of the file, since it will be interpreted as boundary)

Comment: I think you do not need to do everything by hand setting the start and end boundary delimiter, since it is taken form the header filed Content-Type once you set it - for reference see RFC 2046, Section 5.1.1. page 22, 23.

Comment: Are you saying, `NSURLConnection` will automatically adding missing fragments of a multipart/form-data message? I've never heard something about such a wondrous feature! Did you confirm your assertions with a packet trace tool (like tcpdump)?

Comment: I am sure you did not check the reference, but nevermind:dash-boundary := "--" boundary
                      ; boundary taken from the value of
                      ; boundary parameter of the
                      ; Content-Type field.

Comment: With all respect, I fear you misinterpreted this: this comment just clarifies, that the _boundary_ value is taken from the Content-Type header (where it is defined). It must of course occur at the beginning of the part. This is how parts are separated from each other. There are several other indication in the RFC that the boundary must occur, including the notion if the dashes preceding the boundary.

Answer (score -3):

In order to render my comment more precisely:

Your code looks *almost* correct, but there are a few issues:

First, a "boundary-delimiter" MUST be preceded by a CRLF. And, conceptually, this preceding CRLF belongs to the "boundary-delimiter.

Second, a "Content-Type" header for parameters won't hurt.

Thus, I would suggest to change the following from

```
// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

to

```
// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendBytes:"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n" length:41];
    // (other headers if any)
    // close headers with CRLF:
    [body appendBytes:"\r\n" length:2];
    // param value:
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
```

Forth, you should not append a CRLF to binary data!
When outputting a part which contains binary data, follow the above lines: as you can see, there is no closing CRLF after writing the parameter value to the body part.

Hence:

```
if (imageData) 
{
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"harryimg1.png\"\r\n",FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];     
}
```

Furthermore, you omitted the "close-boundary-delimiter:

After the last part, add the following:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

A last CRLF is not required, but won't hurt also.

#### Edit

Further notes:

It's not recommended to use `NSURLConnection`'s convenient class method sendSynchronousRequest: when sending large data. You are better of implementing NSURLConnection delegates which lets you cancel the request, when something goes wrong, and also gives more control.

Furthermore, this approach uses a `NSData` as the request body of the multipart/form-data message. This requires that the while body must fit into memory. This can lead to memory issues. A more robust approach would utilize a input stream as request body, but this implementation is much more complex (really MUCH more).

iOS 7 has a new API where it should be more easy to transmit large files. Please consult the documentation of `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionUploadTask`.

Comment: I would like to know why people down vote this. Obviously it didn't work for you? If so, please tell what's your issue! Please note that composing a multipart message "by hand" is quite error prone. Show your code if you have issues.